# Cucumber is very slow when running tests [Tested on two different Fedora machines]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd

I am new to BDD. Every time I try using cucumber, I find it pretty slow. I have tried with Rails 3.0.9 & 3.1 on two different machines. One of machines is an old IBM thinkpad laptop with 2 GB ram; and the other one is a PC with 4 GB RAM [I can get exact specifications if required]. Both run Fedora 14.

Even with a new application with no scnerios Cucumber take minutes. Here is how it goes:

```
$ cucumber 
Using the default profile...
--- about 2 minutes delay---- and then it says:
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s
```

In contrast, Rspec is instant:

```
rspec
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00005 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```

While cucumber says it took 0m0.000s ; it has taken about 2 minutes in reality. And, RSpec was instant and shows the time correctly as well: 0.00005 seconds.

Is this normal. Do I need some additional Gems Or settings to make the process faster.

Update: Here is more data:

First with cucumber:

```
$time cucumber
Using the default profile...
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s

real    0m53.489s
user    0m37.051s
sys 0m1.973s
```

and then with rspec

```
$ time rspec spec/
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00005 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures

real    0m1.925s
user    0m1.032s
sys 0m0.155s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're blaming the slowness on the wrong tool. What's slow is Ruby and Rails' startup time, not Cucumber. This is well known.

Comment: Thanks! so what's the solution. And why is rspec faster!

Comment: My tests are running slow at the moment but my application is in PHP.

Comment: I would like to say that @Aslak was correct. And, I think having gotten some experience with Cucumber I think it is rather unfair that he got -4 for this.

Answer (score 9):

Ok. Used Spork, and here is the data again:

Rspec is faster then earlier even with no examples, I can feel the difference:

```
$ time rspec --drb spec/

Finished in 0.00182 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures

real    0m1.495s
user    0m0.952s
sys 0m0.147s
```

And Here is the data for Cucumber:

... suspense....

```
$ time cucumber --drb
Using the default profile...
Disabling profiles...
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s

real    0m3.775s
user    0m2.187s
sys 0m0.367s
```

Wow, there is marked difference now. If you get "undefined method `World' for main:Object (NoMethodError)" Please use spork version 0.9.0.rc9.

Update: Here are the steps, if someone else needs them [Ruby 1.9.2 + Rails 3.1]:

Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rails3-generators'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc9'
end
```

Then, run bundle install:

```
bundle install
```

[If you are using rspec]

```
rails g rspec:install
spork --bootstrap
```

edit spec/spec_helper.rb and follow instructions. Basically put everything between

```
Spork.prefork do
end
```

for cucumber:

```
rails g cucumber:install --spork
```

Run spork

```
bundle exec spork cuc
```

Run tests:

```
rspec --drb spec/
cucumber --drb
```

Enjoy BDD!! Autotest next!

Update:

You can add --drb to .rspec to run rspec without the --drb option.

Update:

Just realized I don't need --drb with cucumber.. with a spork server running, following would be sufficient:

```
cucumber features/
```

Comment: Wow - so much better!!  Just a quick note.... to get the benefits of this you must run cucumber as listed above (e.g. just plain `cucumber` or `cucumber --profile wip`) **NOT** `bundle exec rake cucumber`.

Comment: Updated the solution for Rails 3.1 .. if someone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not the only one, I stopped using cucumber because it just took too long on my computer. My RSpec is a little bit slow only if I get a lot of examples (70-100ish) compared to the Rails-casts and other peoples tutorials I've watched but to me its fine(10-12 sec). Cucumber took the same amount of time on mine, my specs are:

```
Windows 7 64bit
Intel i3 3.19 Ghz
4.00 Gb Ram
```

And it still drags ass, it's annoying that I have to upgrade my computer just to get this to run fast! It a could be Windows 7 thing.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and have delay about 20 seconds before test running

Comment: In railscasts tests runs immediately))

Comment: On Windows, Ruby is slow in general. Also, I have seen other questions about Cucumber being slow on Windows.

Comment: In railscasts Ryan Bates cuts all delays and so on. He told how he makes screencasts.